# How to detect service is idle in a C# web api rest application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-web-api

I have service running, and I want to detect if it has been idle for 5 min. If so I want to trigger a method call in my c# code.

Is there a way to detect an idle time for a web api rest service in C#?
I am running my service on kestrel, but it needs to work in a docker hosted a container as well.

I have searched both here on stackoverflow and Google, but I can only find idle time in reference to winform applications.

Comment: Can you define "idle"?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of idle? No requests for 5min? A very simple approach: You can just have e.g. middleware that schedules (i. e. sets a timer on the first request/ resets the timer once it has already been set) a method call in 5 min once a request comes in. If no request comes in the timer will trigger the method 5mins after the last request came in. Where you place the middleware in your pipeline is determined by what you consider idle.

Comment: are we talking abut windows service or web api hosted in the iis ?

Comment: AFAIK I know there is no built-in way to do this. You'd have to build something yourself. How exactly you'd do this depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. With idle I mean that there haven't been any incoming requests for like 5 minutes. I am not hosting it on IIS, but I will host it in a docker container.  I think having a timer being reset everytime a request has been registered sounds like an idea. I had hoped I could use something built-in. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Since you've tagged your question with Docker, it's worth considering scaling. If you have more than one instance of your application running, does 'idle' mean no requests for each container or no requests for all containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this from the .Net side like this:

Create a service for the task that you want to be triggered:

```
public class IdleTimeTrackerService
{
    private readonly ILogger<IdleTimeTrackerService> _logger;

    public IdleTimeTrackerService(ILogger<IdleTimeTrackerService>logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
// call your method here
        _logger.LogInformation("Sample Service did something.");
    }
}
```

Create a periodic hosted service which implements background service.

```
public class PeriodicHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    public readonly TimeSpan _period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    private readonly ILogger<PeriodicHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _factory;
    private int _executionCount = 0;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        // Cancel the current timer
        _cts.Cancel();

        // Create a new timer
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public PeriodicHostedService(
        ILogger<PeriodicHostedService> logger,
        IServiceScopeFactory factory)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _logger = logger;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(_period);

            while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(_period, _cts.Token);
                    await using AsyncServiceScope asyncScope = _factory.CreateAsyncScope();
                    IdleTimeTrackerService idleTimeTrackerService = asyncScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IdleTimeTrackerService>();
                    await idleTimeTrackerService.DoSomethingAsync();
                    _executionCount++;
                    _logger.LogInformation(
                        $"Executed PeriodicHostedService - Count: {_executionCount}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(
                        $"Execution of PeriodicHostedService skipped with exception message {ex.Message}. Good luck next round!");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Write a middleware that resets the timer (periodic timer doesn't provide a method to reset the timer but with an workaround we did in step 2 through skipping the service call when cancel is requested), we provided a method named ResetTimer, which will be called from this middleware:

```
public class ChangeStateMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly PeriodicHostedService _service;

    public ChangeStateMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, PeriodicHostedService service)
    {
        _next = next;
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        _service.ResetTimer();
        Console.WriteLine($"Service timer reset successfully!");
        await _next(context);   
    }
}
```

In `program.cs` register the services and use the middleware like this:

```
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IdleTimeTrackerService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PeriodicHostedService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService(
    provider => provider.GetRequiredService<PeriodicHostedService>());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<ChangeStateMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```